# Is it possible to define a function as itself?

Tags: recursion, cs50

I'm having trouble understanding this line of code. If you are familiar with the collatz function, here is a snapshot of what it means

Is it possible to define a code as itself.

Context: The collatz conjecture applies to positive integers and speculates that it is possible to get back to 1 if you follow these steps:

If n is 1, stop
If n is even, repeat this process on n/2
If n is odd, repeat this process on 3n+1.

As an example, say, if n is 3:
3---->10---->5----->16--->8----->4----->2----> ( number of steps required: 1)

Write a function to identify the number of steps required to get to 1 if you start from one and recurse as abvove.

In the line of code below, in particular the calculation of the number of steps required to reduce an even number to 1. I am referring to                       else if (n % 2) == 0
    return 1 + collatz (n/2)

How can you use a function when you've barely even defined it? ( i.e collatz).

```
int collatz ( int n)
{

    // base case
    if (n ==1)
        return 0; 
    // even numbers
    else if (n % 2 )== 0)
        return 1 + collatz(n/2)
    //odd numbers
    else
        return 1 + collatz(3*n + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can you use a function when you've barely even defined it?

Everything you need to *write* a call to the function was defined in the first line:

```
int collatz(int n)
```

So inside `collatz()`, even though you haven't finished writing it, you know you can call `collatz()` with an `int` argument and expect an `int` result.

What we can't do is *run* the function before we're finished defining it.

Answer (score -1):

```
def collatz(x):
print(x)
i = 1
while x != 1:
    if (x % 2) == 0:
        x = x/2
        print(x)
        i += 1
    else:
        x = 3*x +1
        print(x)
        i +=1
print("Steps:", i)
```

I used a while loop to check for when we got down to 1.